# What is the correct way to inject dependency in Angular parameter

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

i just started learning angular last year, and i stumbled upon angular dependency injection. The case is i need to inject dependency that require some parameter to instantiate. Currently i'm doing it like this:

some-dependency.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ConfigService } from 'app/services/config.service';
import { Client } from 'some-dependency';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
    useFactory: (config:ConfigService) => new Client({
        host:config.clientURL, maxRetries: config.maxRetry
    }),
    deps: [ConfigService]
})

export class SomeDependencyService extends Client {

}
```

another-service.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { SomeDependencyService } from 'app/services/some-dependency.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class SomeService {

    constructor( private deps: SomeDependencyService ) {}

    getSomething() {
        return this.deps.get('something');
    }
}
```

The code works fine, and i can get `Client` instance without instantiate it inside `another-service.ts` with no problem plus i can easily mock it for unit testing, but i'm not sure if this is the correct way to do DI with parameter in Angular, and i'm also not sure if this code will generate any unexpected behaviour.

While i can just import the dependency inside the services that need it, and instantiate the dependency locally, but that would be very annoying if i have a lot services (and components) that require the dependency.

thanks

Comment: Why don't you just inject the ConfigService into the constructor of SomeDependencyService?